# prove $a \equiv b \pmod{p_1}$ and $a \equiv b \pmod{p_2} \Rightarrow a \equiv b \pmod{p_1\times p_2}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am following a proof of an RSA algorithm and the proof states the following:

$p_1$ and $p_2$ are distinct primes,
$a \equiv b \pmod{p_1}$ and $a \equiv b \pmod{p_2} \Rightarrow a \equiv b \pmod{p_1\times p_2}$. Let's call that FACT X.

can someone give me a proof for this. i have no formal mathematical training so a detailed proof will be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to clarify the nature of the $p_i$.  Are they, say, distinct primes?  (the claim is false if $p_1=p_2$)

Comment: yes they are distinct primes

Comment: That should appear in the question, not just a comment.  I'll post something below.

Comment: thanks mentioned it in the question

Comment: This follows from the chinese remainder theorem I think.

Comment: @M.Van, yes it was mentioned in the proof but it is difficult for me to understand, would you mind explaining it?

Comment: You say you have no formal mathematical training. I can explain it easily if you know about bijections and about $\mathbb{Z}_n$, the group of residue classes mod n. Do you know these concepts?

Comment: i understand bijection, one to one and onto when we are talking about bijective functions. From what you mention about Zn, i have a feeling that Zn is the set of possible values created by mod n, the integers 1 to n - 1 am i correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We note that $$p_1|(a-b)\implies a-b=p_1m$$  for some integer $m$.

But then we have $p_2|p_1m\implies p_2|m$ (if a prime divides a product then it divides at least one of the factors and we know that $p_2$ does not divide $p_1$).  Thus $m=p_2n$ for some integer $n$, whence $a-b=p_1p_2n$  so $p_1p_2|a-b$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the key fact:

> If $u$ and $v$ divide $w$, then $lcm(u,v)$ divides $w$.

Apply this to $u=p_1$, $v=p_2$ and $w=a-b$, noting that $lcm(p_1,p_2)=p_1 p_2$ because $p_1\ne p_2$.